# how to execute two input just pushing one

Tags: forms

Someone maybe can help me
i have a FORM with two INPUT. when I have finished entering, I must first press Enter and then press the second INPUT. that's how it goes. But I would like to finish the input when in, execute the entire form when pressing ENTER or after entering (without pressing ENTER), execute it by pressing second input
thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="nl">
 <form id="text" method='post' >
   <input  type='text' name='username' 
    maxlength='5px' style=" width='5px'"  >

   <input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),
            $('#voiceselection').val());" 
            type="button" 
           value="Play" />
</form>

<script>

   var var3='mevrouw'+"  "+"<?php echo $vNaam ?>"+" "+"<?php echo $aNaam ? 
   >"+" "+'welkom';
   }
 document.getElementById("text").value = var3;
    //Populate voice selection dropdown

    var voicelist = responsiveVoice.getVoices();
    var vselect = $("#voiceselection");
    $.each(voicelist, function() {
            vselect.append($("<option 
    />").val(this.name).text(this.name));
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: some correction

Comment: Som correction.   Someone maybe can help me
i have a FORM with two INPUT. when I have finished entering, I must first press Enter and then press the second INPUT. that's how it goes. But I would like to execute the entire form after entering and pressing ENTER or after entering (without pressing ENTER), execute it by pressing second input
thanks